# Filesize difference - CMD & Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, filesystems, cmd.exe

When I'm doing a dir of a folder (in CMD) and I look at the filesize, it difference from the filesize that Windows Explorer is giving me (in the detailed view).

Is this normal behaviour?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moreover, if you highlight a particular file in Windows Explorer the detailed view, then you can see another size in the status bar!

The file size is still the same but **displayed** with different algorithms.

- `dir` command displays size in bytes
- Explorer status bar in kilobytes
- Explorer detail in kilobytes of disk used

Right-click a file, choose *Properties* and see the *General* tab: there you can see all that numbers gathered (together)... A big file size could be shown in mega- or gigabytes instead...

To be more confused :) you could count up there what that *kilobyte* word stands for: whether kB (SI kilo=1000) or kiB (IEC kibi=1024), cf. e.g. [Binary prefix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix)